# No Method Error for "comments", can't find and correct the nil value to make the comment post

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, comments, polymorphic-associations

I'm relatively new to rails and am trying to pull off my first polymorphic association with comments.

I am running rails 3.2.3

Edit - When I try to post a comment, my log is returning this error:

```
Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-20 13:17:38 -0700
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"SOLcF71+WpfNLtpBFpz2qOZVaqcVCHL2AVZWwM2w0C4=", "comment"=>{"text"=>"Test this comment"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 101 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 126ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `Comment' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

I have tried out many different solutions offered on SO and elsewhere, including the answer from Jordan below, due, I'm sure, to my own inexperience, but have been unable to resolve the error.

The trace calls out line 13 in the Comments Controller and I commented after that line below to mark the error:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comments = @commentable.comments
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end

  def create
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment]) #<<<<LINE 13

    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created comment."
      redirect_to :id => nil
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def find_commentable
    params.each do |name, value|
      if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
        return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
      end
    end

    nil
  end
end
```

Posts Controller:

```
def show
@post = Post.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html  # show.html.erb
  format.json  { render :json => @post }
end
end
```

Comment template (in post show)

```
<ul id="comments">
  <% if @comments %>
     <h2>Comments</h2>
         <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
        <li><%= comment.text %></li>
      <% end %>
  <% else %>
       <h2>Comment:</h2>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= simple_form_for [@commentable,Comment.new], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', :multipart => true } do |f| %>
   <fieldset>
       <%= f.input :text %>
       Upload Photo <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Post show:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<div class="row">
<div class="span2 offset1">
   <%= image_tag @post.photo.url(:show) %>
</div>
    <div class="span5">
            <h1><%= @post.title %></h1>
            <p><%= @post.index_text.html_safe %></p>
           <p><%= @post.show_text.html_safe %></p>
            <%= render "comments/comment" %>
            <%= render "comments/form" %>
            <% if can? :update, @course %>
                <%= link_to 'Edit Post', edit_post_path(@post), :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
                <%= link_to 'Delete Post', @post, 
                                    confirm: 'Are you sure?', 
                                    method: :delete, 
                                    :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
                 <%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path, :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
            <% end %>
     </div>

<nav class="span2 offset1">
    <ul class="well">
        <li>Category 1</li>
        <li>Category 2</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
<div class="row offset2">
    <%= link_to 'Back to Posts', posts_path, :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
</div>
```

Routes:

```
  resources :posts, :has_many => :comments
  resources :comments
```

It is probably something obvious that someone with more experience can resolve. Let me know if anything comes to mind. Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both of the above answers, but the problem continued.

I ended up consulting with a friend who suggested the following solution, which I like because it's more elegant than my original attempt and easier to read (for later, when I or someone else need to return to the code):

```
def find_commentable
  if params[:post_id]
    Post.find(params[:post_id])
  #elsif params[:other_id]
  #  Other.find(params[:other_id])
  else
    # error out?
  end
end
```

The commented out section will refer to other associations once I get them up and running.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `@commentable` is `nil`, which means that `CommentsController#find_commentable` is returning `nil`. I think your regular expression is sound, so that means one of two things is happening in `find_commentable`:

1. There aren't any keys in `params` that match your regex.
2. Your regex is matching but there aren't any records in the resulting table with the id in `value`.

Debug this as usual by inspecting `params` and the records in your database to make sure they look like you expect them to look.

Comment: Hey Jordan, thanks for the quick reply. I think you're probably right, but although I am getting to know rails, I don't know Ruby very well, so when you say "debug this as usual," I don't know what "as usual" means. Can you point me somewhere where I can research how to do something like this for the first time?

Comment: I've tried several things, but everything seems to be in order in my models and in the controllers and I'm still getting the error. If anyone can see the issue, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your find_commentable method.

Here are the params passed to your CommentsController#create:

```
Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-20 13:17:38 -0700
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"SOLcF71+WpfNLtpBFpz2qOZVaqcVCHL2AVZWwM2w0C4=", "comment"=>{"text"=>"Test this comment"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment"}
```

Here is your CommentsController#create:

```
def create
  @commentable = find_commentable
  @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment]) #<<<<LINE 13


def find_commentable
  params.each do |name, value|
    if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
      return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
    end
  end

  nil
end
```

As you can see, find_commentable expects a param like xx_id (for example, comments_id) which it uses to search for an appropriate class (in case of comments_id, it will be Comment), otherwise it returns nil. Refer [classify and constantize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-classify) here.

Your params do not contain any such param. So, you always get a nil object.

Your find_commentable needs some rework. I think in case of nested_fields, it should be an expression like

```
/(.+)_attributes$/
```

instead of

```
/(.+)_id$/.
```

And you need to have

```
:accepts_nested_attributes_for :commentable
```

in your Comment model class.

Comment: Hey Salil, I continued to have problems on my side while trying to make the original code work and a friend suggested rewriting the code from scratch (below), but wanted to say thank you for your post.